# Trying to set multiple array variables' values in Backstretch

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set Featured images attached to Posts as the source of Backstretch jQuery on the Posts page in WordPress.

I am able to successfully create multiple variables and set the 'src' parameter of these to the URLs of Posts' featured images like this via functions.php: http://cl.ly/image/2i2m3H1W2z25 (Screenshot from HTML source).

In the backstretch-set.js, I have:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

var i = 0;

$( ".post-image" ).each(function() {

    var BackStretchImg_temp = 'BackStretchImg' + i;

    // console.log(BackStretchImg_temp);

    $(this).backstretch([BackStretchImg_temp.src],{duration:3000,fade:750});

    i++;
});
});
```

But .post-image divs aren't getting the value of the 'src' of variables. http://cl.ly/image/41422N1w2i33

I am trying to set BackStretchImg0's 'src' value as the backstretch image for first occurrence of .post-image, BackStretchImg1's 'src' value for second occurrence of .post-image and so on..

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first post, forgive me if I'm not doing stuff correctly!

I quickly put this concept together with HTML using Coda..

I added a data attribute to the div we want the image to go into. This could be added in the loop.

Stylesheet

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: tan;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.post {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.entry-image {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    $( ".container .post .entry-image" ).each( function(){
        var post_image = $(this).data( "entryimage" );
        console.log( "post_image: "+ post_image );
        $(this).backstretch([BackStretchImg]=post_image,{duration:3000,fade:750});
    });
});
```

I had the test code as this:

```
<div class="container">

<article class="post post-1">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title">Entry Title</h2>
        <div class="entry-image" data-entryimage="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=post-1.png"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>This is the entry</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <div class="entry-meta">Meta</div>
    </footer>
</article>

<article class="post post-2">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title">Entry Title</h2>
        <div class="entry-image" data-entryimage="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=post-2.png"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>This is the entry</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <div class="entry-meta">Meta</div>
    </footer>
</article>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used your method and blogged about the same here:

http://sridharkatakam.com/applying-backstretch-multiple-featured-images-genesis/